# LIVE 16.04.5 and 18.04.3 USB Drives DO Boot but I do not have any image on the Screen, though the sound for desktop being ready is heard

Tags: boot, nvidia, usb

I Have a Insys Notebook running 14.04.5 and would like to upgrade to either 16.04.5 or 18.04.3 by running a LIVE Usb drive (already done).

(model M761SU) (Intel Pentium(R) dual T3400 @ 2,16 Mhz x2) with an nVIDIA graphics card 9300M GS ( vbios revision 62.98.2E.00.A1) Build date (08-01-2008)

Apparently the boot sequence with those two versions of LIVE usb sticks running 16.04.5 or 18.04.3, takes place as I can notice the flashing Led in the USB flash drive and finally the desktop ready chime once the os is fully loaded.

What could be missing here?
Could anybody help (step by step)

After the rescue from "sudodus"
I was able to boot the 16.04.5 usb pen drive by invoking the ESC key while at the beginning of boot sequence started and then a bottom options function keys were available, from F1 to F6 and this latter one enabled me to choose "nomodeset" recommended by "sudodus".
it did boot with screen, and was able to install it.
So, so far the machine has booted up and the display was rather "small" and the driver being used was an x.org nouveau driver (open source).
I am installing a proprietary version of the nVidia driver which is  340.107 version from nVidia, by invoking the "additional drivers" routine to install it.
Lets hope it works ok.
I'll be back to tell the full story here.

thanks so far for the help given.

After installing the driver mentioned earlier, the machine did not boot anymore.
Installed twice again with the same prerequisites, mentioned by "sudodus" and once installed again could not boot it up to configura another driver for the graphics card from Nvidia, i.e. a legacy version of it that was available to install but have chosen the newer version at the first attempt. 
Going back to 14.04.5 which boots the machine properly and installs properly.
As a newbie I am not aware of what the reason could be, for sure the proper driver is not present on the 16.04.5 and 18.04.3 iso images. I guess...

No, something is terribly wrong, as with 16.04.5, 14.04.5 installs properly but on the boot sequence i get a blinking cursor ate the top left corner of the screen and nothing happens.

Do not understand what is wrong now.

Comment: to others: note that this question is indeed [on-topic](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) on AU: “unless the question is asking how to upgrade to a supported release”

Comment: With nvidia graphics, I think you need the [boot option](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808) `nomodeset`.